# How to make tournament grid / table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls

I need to create tournament grid for football matches,
something like  : [image: that]

How to do that in best way ? Some ideas or cocoacontrols?

Comment: Try to use collection view controller

Answer (score 0):

Is this for iPad or iPhone ?

If for iPad you can go with UISPlitViewController

Check this : http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/

If for iPhone then you can go with UICollectionView itself.

Comment: How do you suppose to create connecting line between cells ? How do you actually suppose to create with collectionView?

Comment: If lines are required then you have to create the CustomView in UISplitViewController with UIView Subviews .